# Zurb Foundation 3 - Full Width Sections & Change Max Width?

Tags: css, html, frameworks, responsive-design, media-queries

Im using [ZURB Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/) on a project of mine. I love grid systems and responsive sites but my issue is I still strongly believe they should be built wider then 1000px.

I have a few questions:

1) First off I would love to make certain sections (divs) full width. Now I have read I can just replace `<div class="row">` with `<div class="container">` for instance and it will generate that effect. Now for some reason this does not feel right, should I just create my own class thats full width, or what would be the proper way to do this?

2) I would love to have it based for a larger resolution, maybe a max 1440px wide or even a fluid 100% full width. How could I go about doing this, and/or is Foundation not the correct framework for me? I love the fact it comes with all the templates so is super quick and friendly to do mockups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Designing for a specific width clashes with the whole concept of responsive design.

Comment: Yes I get that, but instead of the default "max-width" of 1000px or 960 for instance I would rather increase the default to 1440px etc. This should not effect the responsiveness. Feel free to elighten me why they always tend to have a max width of 940-1000px?

Comment: @cimmanon he wasn't asking how to create a specific width, he was asking how to set the maximum design width provided in the Foundation framework. Max-width != width

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** Please stop down voting this post. The framework has changed significantly since the question was answered. If you are using Foundation 4 or higher, please see the updated answers and up vote them.

**For Early versions of Foundation 3 only**
Add the following override to your CSS (This must appear after or at the end of foundation.css)

```
.row {
     width: 100%;
}
```

This will override the default with of the framework and make the design go full screen. Feel free to change this value to suit your needs.

There is also a customized download available at http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php (which probably does the same thing, overrides or replaces .row width)

Comment: awesome thank you, ideally I could just create a new class called ".full-row" for instance and just make that 100% as well correct?

I did see the custom download version, but it says max-width and I assumed that was just for the mobile version...because the value of row to me seems to be 1000px and the default download max width is 940px.

Comment: I'm not sure how adding a new .full-row class will work. There are several CSS classes that piggyback their selectors off of the .row class. I would examine foundation.css before implementing that change.

Comment: So to expand on this how could I make only the header full width?

Comment: If you only want the header full with then make the header outside of the grid. Examples: www.tubeturns.com | www.mctconsultingandtraining.com | www.xtremecleaningsolutions.com

Comment: If you're working in Foundation 4 (which many people who end up on this question may be now), you'll need to use min-width rather than width: .row {min-width:100% !important; }

Comment: might also help to just create a class .full if you want only certain rows to be 100%. ie. class="row full"

Answer (score 7):

Editing/overriding foundation is easy. In Foundation 4 you can edit your _settings.scss file. Uncomment out $row-width: emCalc(some_number.px); to a row-width you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

Uncommenting `$row-width: rem-calc(1000);` worked for me